# VBA Macro Selected Text Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro i wrote in vba to get selected text in an email message and for now show it in a MsgBox.

This works great when i run the macro with selected text in an email message with the email message opened in its own window.

when i try this with the text selected in the email pane of the main outlook program it gives me an error "Object variable or With block variable not set" this is coming from the "Set insp" line

any ideas?

```
Sub showseltext()

Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector

Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector

If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
Set msg = insp.CurrentItem

If insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
Set hed = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
Set appWord = hed.Application
Set rng = appWord.Selection
MsgBox (rng)
End If

End If

Set appWord = Nothing
Set insp = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set hed = Nothing
Set msg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to check to see if the inspector is nothing and if it is then oyu need to utilize the explorer object.  Here is your code written to include that check

```
Sub showseltext()

Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector

If Application.ActiveInspector Is Nothing Then
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Class = olMail Then
            Set msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        End If
    Else
        'to many items selected
        MsgBox "Please select one email"
    End If
Else
    Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set msg = insp.CurrentItem
    End If
End If

If msg Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "could not determine the mail item"
Else
    If msg.GetInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        Set hed = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
        Set appWord = hed.Application
        Set Rng = appWord.Selection
        MsgBox (Rng)
    End If
End If

Set appWord = Nothing
Set insp = Nothing
Set Rng = Nothing
Set hed = Nothing
Set msg = Nothing

End Sub
```