# Get selected text from subject line

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129226/vba-macro-selected-text-outlook-2010) answer but it won't seem to work for me.  I need to get the selected (highlighted) text from the subject of the email.  When I try the linked solution from either the preview pane or from an open email, I only get the first character of the body.  I attempted to look at all properties of mail.GetInspector.WordEditor but nothing seems to contain the selected text.  As stated, mail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection only has the first character of the body. In my code, I have mail as type MailItem and is set to ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).

My code works fine when the selected text is in the body of the email.

Comment: Edit your post and show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the Windows control containing the subject and send WM_GETTEXT message to it.

I don't think you can do that in VBA.